# Sql query joining

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a query through which I am selecting all Id form a table

```
SELECT emp_id FROM emp_table
```

Now I have to select all of those Emp name from another table In one query

```
SELECT emp_name FROM emp_detail WHERE emp_id='".THAT ID."'
```

Comment: You need to ask a question. Also, what are the tables involved, what is their structure, how are they related to each other and what do you expect the result to look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a join

```
Select d.emp_name from emp_table t join emp_detail d on t.emp_id = d.emp_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT emp_name 
FROM emp_detail 
WHERE emp_id in (SELECT emp_id FROM emp_table)
```

or

```
SELECT d.emp_name 
FROM emp_detail d
inner join emp_table e on e.emp_id = d.emp_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT dtl.emp_name --other columns
FROM emp_table emp
JOIN emp_detail dtl
  ON emp.id = dtl.emp_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT d.emp_name, e.emp_id
FROM emp_detail d
inner join emp_table e on e.emp_id = d.emp_id and e.emp_id='".ParameterID."';
```

OR

```
SELECT d.emp_name, e.emp_id
FROM emp_table e
inner join emp_detail d on e.emp_id = d.emp_id where e.emp_id='".ParameterID."';
```

You can remove ParameterID id part of query if you dont need.